# What was it that Jobe couldn't put his finger on while watching the camp Genoa feed?

Tags: plot-explanation, banshee

Before the camp Genoa job in *Banshee*, Job was watching the feed from the camp over and over, exclaiming that all seems same everyday but there is something he can't put his finger on.

What was it that Job couldn't put his finger on? Did it become apparent during the job?

The scene is in episode 7 from season 3, ["You Can’t Hide From the Dead"](http://banshee.wikia.com/wiki/You_Can%E2%80%99t_Hide_From_the_Dead), at around 06:40m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this recap/review by **Michael Stets** for **Nerdcore Movement**](http://www.nerdcoremovement.com/banshee-recap-season-3-episode-7-you-cant-hide-from-the-dead/):

> **Job has already expressed deep concern for Hood’s mental status** and
>   when his friend arrives home at the trailer, he is sitting inside
>   waiting for him (wearing a “Paws” shirt, a hilarious spoof on Jaws).
>   He tells him he wants to delay the heist at Camp Genoa because **he
>   feels Hood is just too distracted and it may get all of them caught**.
>   Hood tells him it’s now or never and they have to do that night. Job
>   is worried and he has every reason to be. The expert computer hacker
>   also voiced his concern to Sugar, who, of course, tells him he worries
>   too much.
>
> [...]
>
> Suddenly, **Hood’s mind starts wandering and he starts having flashbacks
>   and visions of Siobhan. As this is happening he doesn’t see one of the
>   mercenaries sneak up on Job and attack him** while he is handling the
>   computers to breach security on the safe. Sugar tries to alert Carrie,
>   but she cannot leave the safe due to time constraints. Finally, Hood
>   snaps out of it and takes out the Marine before he compromises the job
>   and Job. **Job is clearly pissed off, especially since he was worried
>   that something like this would happen.**